# Nginx redirect all subdomains to http://example.com instead of http://blog.example.com

Tags: subdomain

So, I had my webserver running fine, I like non-www domains so I would leave non-www active, but whenever user would type www, they could also access the non-www version normally.

Then I created a subdomain http://blog.example.com. Now all traffic that goes to www.example.com load blog.example.com instead of example.com

I'm using nginx on digital ocean.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of [stuff](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) going on behind the scenes that determines which domain will load by default in an nginx installation.  The easiest way to address you issue is to have the "server_name" directive set properly in your config file for example.com.  Something similar to the following should address your issue:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com
```

This will tell nginx to load the specific example.com configuration for both the www and non-www domains.

Comment: good! what if I want to keep the "www" on the url when they access it?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www for www redirecting.